# Contactless Java Card | EMVco | Banking Applet

Tags: smartcard, javacard, emv

I am new to java card world.
I have series of questions.

> 1) Does contactless java carda are really allowed for banking? If yes
>   how to apply  for visa or mastercard applet on java card ?
>
> 2) Does single java card supports Multiple-Applications like visa-app,
>   mastercard-app, xyz-app?
>
> 3) What data is exchanged between Payment Terminal and contactless
>   java card which has lets say visa applet on it? Is that protocol
>   public ?
>
> 4) How to set up a visa java card simulation set up to simulate payments on actual payment terminal ?

Comment: In case you wonder why your question is downvoted: You've posted 4 questions in one. It is easier for people to find questions and answers if each entry is exactly one question in the headline, and a description of the question in the body text. In your case, you should have posted 4 questions.

Answer (score 4):

1) Whether a contactless Java Card is allowed for banking depends on whether it has the corresponding type approval. Which type approvals are needed depends on the bank and the banking application. Typical type approvals that are needed are Common Criteria and the Master Card type approval. Common Criteria will not only be applied to various elements of the card itself (like the chip, the OS and the application), but also to the development organization (building security, IT security etc.).

2) Yes, a single Java Card supports multiple applications. For example, a modern SIM cards like G&D SkySIM CX (which even simultaneously supports NFC (ISO 14443 via SWP) besides ISO 7816) hosts a variety of applications at the same time: The GlobalPlatform Card Manager application, ETSI GSM/UICC application, MIFARE, MasterCard, Visa, several applications from the telco provider, and even a Smart Card Web Server. Java Card smart cards that support multiple applications usually implement the GlobalPlatform specification to manage the life cycle of the card as well as the life cycle of those applications (authentication / authorization, loading, installation, memory allocation / quota, selection, deselection, termination).

3) The protocol consists of multiple layers, most of which are public. The lower layers, like ISO 7816, which describes the "packets" (APDUs) and general characteristics of smart cards, ISO 14443, which describes the characteristics of contactless cards, SWP, which describes the situation when using a contact-based card's ISO 7816 C6 Pin to delegate ISO 14443 to a contactless frontend, Global Platform and Java Card are public. I'm not sure, however, how public the specifications of Visa and MasterCard are.

4) For such a simulation, you need to simulate the terminal-side as well. Your applet needs to implement the Application side of the Visa specification, and your terminal needs to run a smart card client application that triggers these commands. This is, however, the normal way of testing basically all smart card applications.

If with "actual payment terminal" you mean a real payment terminal, you will not be able to run your simulation with that because you would not have the required secrets (keys etc.). The actual payment terminal would first recognize your Visa applet, but then reject it because it lacks the correct keys. Testing is always done with special test keys, and real keys are usually not available during development. Depending on the application, either the real keys might get inserted during the personalization of the application, or the application is generated with card-specific keys which have to register with a background server. For details, you'd have to consult the corresponding specification.

Comment: Concerning answer two: dual interface is different from multi-application. SInce 14443 is a communication protocol, ISO 7816 part 4/8/9 for the respective commands could still apply, only part 3 for T=0, T=1 is parallel.

Comment: The point was not about dual interface, but about the fact that the modern SIM cards run payment applications besides the GSM/UICC application. I will clarify that. Thanks for the feedback.